# Django block.super doesn't render variable set in parent template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, template-inheritance

I have the following scenario:

## 2 views:

### view1:

```
return render(request, 'template1.html', {'var1': 'value1'} )
```

### view2:

```
return render(request, 'template2.html', {'var2': 'value2' } )
```

## 2 templates:

### template1.html

```
{% block foo %}
{{ var1 }}
{% endblock %}
```

### template2.html

```
{% extends template1.html %}
{% block foo %}
{{ block.super }}
{{ var2 }}
{% endblock %}
```

### Desired Output of Template1.html:

```
value1
```

### Real Output of Template1.html:

```
value1
```

### Desired Outputof Template2.html:

```
value1 value2
```

### Real Output:

```
value2
```

Why is the value of 'var1' not output when I call {{block.super}}?

I have the  'django.core.context_processors.request', in my settings.py defined. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

template2.html extends template1.html, but that does not mean view2 extends view1. You need to add var1 to the context information in view2.

```
# view2
return render(request, 'template2.html', {
    'var1': 'value1',
    'var2': 'value2'
})
```

Comment: This makes sense to. But my problem is related to breadcrumbs, so the page doesn't necessarily know its parent. Do I have to use Session variables here? Seems a bit excessive to me just for this task...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide `var1`in the context in `view2` then how do you think the template will get it ? Change your `settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` to something else than the empty string and you'll know why `var1` doesn't show up...